# How to disable/remove only first space on Multiple input field?

Tags: javascript

How to disable/remove only first space on Multiple input field?
In this example how to use multiple input fields.  [DEMO HERE](http://jsbin.com/foyetolo/9/edit?html,js,output)

```js
$(function() {
  $('body').on('keydown', '#test', function(e) {
    console.log(this.value);
    if (e.which === 32 &&  e.target.selectionStart === 0) {
      return false;
    }  
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="test">
  <label>Mobile</label>
  <input type="text" id="test1">
  <label>Comments</label>
  <input type="text" id="test2">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is demo? Can you add proper link?

Comment: Where's the question ? :/

Comment: now updated the link

Comment: Is it keycode that you should be checking out? Sorry about it. Even which contains same info. But JSfiddle that I have referenced is working fine

Comment: I am unable to enter space in the first position. What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: @eshunsharma in all fairness the topic is the question. But sure, a question in the text is good to have.

Comment: This question has no PHP. Removed tag

Comment: @Andreas its difficult to understand the question without any code / explanation which in this case wasn't present, but now is. :)

Comment: my question is when add three input tag link name, mobile, comments, then what i should write in JS

Comment: When you add three input tags, what is the output you are looking for?

Comment: it must show the demo format like first space(character) is disable

Comment: I am extremely sorry. I still didnt get what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Now am update html code, i need all the input feilds must show the example demo format

Comment: updated fiddle. Check if that is what you are looking for?

Comment: Fiddle is not working http://jsbin.com/foyetolo/9/edit?html,js,output to check and compare my html code

Comment: "How to disable/remove only first space on Multiple input field?" This is your initial question. What I understood from this is, you want to disable first space character in different input fields. Your jsbin does it on single input field and my fiddle does it on multiple input fields. Please make it more clear on what you are trying to achieve.  You are just disabling text field in your jsbin. What you want me to compare in your html code and jsbin?

Comment: jsbin demo was only one input field but i need 3 input field as same output ,now wt should i want to change in JS

Comment: http://jsbin.com/foyetolo/9/edit?html,js,output    something like this?

Comment: $(function() {
  $('body').on('keydown', '#test', function(e) {
    console.log(this.value);
    if (e.which === 32 &&  e.target.selectionStart === 0) {
      return false;
    }  
  });
});      in this code #test is first feild id ,now how to change 2 and 3 field  test1,test2 id

Comment: you want to change id's of test1 and test2? when do you want this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should be using keycode

Check this https://jsfiddle.net/qn09n676//

```
e.keyCode === 32
```